# Sending send to a TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, jtextarea

I am working on an assignment, but I cannot seem to get my text to print out in the `TextArea`. I'm working on using recursive methods,and I need to send the result from the recursive method to the `TextArea`. I have tried multiple things and it has not worked, and searched the web to no avail. Please help!

```
public class Sheppard_Week5 extends Application {
Button convert = new Button("Convert");
Button clear = new Button("Clear");
Button exitBtn =  new Button("Exit");
Label enterInt = new Label("Enter Number:");
TextField enterText = new TextField();
TextArea binaryText = new TextArea();
ImageView mCEscher = new ImageView("sheppard_week5/M.C.Escher.jpg");
ArrayList<String> remainderList = new ArrayList();
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(binaryText)

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane bPane = new BorderPane();
    GridPane gPane = new GridPane();
    gPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fffaf0;");
    bPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fffaf0;");
    bPane.setCenter(gPane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(bPane);
    bPane.setBottom(buttonBox());
    bPane.setTop(titleBox());

    mCEscher.setFitHeight(300);
    mCEscher.setFitWidth(300);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints();
        column.setPercentWidth(25);
        gPane.getColumnConstraints().add(column);
    }

    /*Gridpane
    *GridPane.setConstraints(node, column Index, row Index, column span, row span);
    */
    gPane.add(enterInt, 0, 0);
    gPane.add(enterText, 1, 0);
    gPane.add(binaryText, 2, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(binaryText, 2, 0, 2, 4);
    gPane.add(mCEscher, 0, 1);
    GridPane.setColumnSpan(mCEscher, 2);
    binaryText.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane.setContent(binaryText);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Binary Converter");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
private VBox titleBox() throws Exception{
    VBox titlesBox = new VBox();
    Text title = new Text("Welcome to GUI #5");
    title.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #000000");
    title.setFont(Font.font("Monospace",FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.REGULAR, 30));
    Text subtitle = new Text("I think this class will be the death of me, "
            + "\nI really wish I could get one thing right...");
    subtitle.setFont(Font.font("Monospace", FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.ITALIC, 10));
    subtitle.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #000000");
    Text subsubtitle = new Text("Please enter an integer.");
    subsubtitle.setFont(Font.font("Monospace", FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.ITALIC, 7));
    subsubtitle.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #000000");
    Text subsubsubtitle = new Text("Please dear God work");
    subsubsubtitle.setFont(Font.font("Monospace", FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.ITALIC, 3));
    subsubsubtitle.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #000000");
    titlesBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    titlesBox.getChildren().addAll(title, subtitle, subsubtitle, subsubsubtitle);
    return titlesBox;
}

private HBox buttonBox() throws Exception{
    HBox buttbox = new HBox();
    buttbox.getChildren().addAll(convert, clear, exitBtn);
    buttbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    buttbox.setMargin(clear,new Insets(10,10,10,10));

    convert.setOnAction(new convertHandler());
    clear.setOnAction(new resetHandler());
    exitBtn.setOnAction(e ->{
        Platform.exit();
    });
    return buttbox;
}

class convertHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        if (enterText.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Warning");
            alert.setHeaderText("Required Fields Empty");
            alert.setContentText("You must enter an integer.\n"
                    + "Please try again.");
            alert.showAndWait();

        } 
        else if (!enterText.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(enterText.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Warning");
                alert.setHeaderText("Field is not an integer");
                alert.setContentText("The entered text is not an integer.\n"
                        + "Please try again.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        } else {
            int enteredNumb = Integer.parseInt(enterText.getText());
            ToBinary(enteredNumb);
            Collections.reverse(remainderList);
            binaryText.appendText("-------------------------------\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < remainderList.size(); i++){
                binaryText.setText(remainderList.get(i));
            }
        }            
    }
}

class resetHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        remainderList.clear();
        binaryText.clear();
        enterText.clear();            
    }
}
public int ToBinary(int number) {
    /* Define variable required in method */
    if (number == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int remainder = number - 2 * (number / 2);
        String remainderString = Integer.toString(remainder);
        String numberString = Integer.toString(number);
        remainderList.add(remainderString);
        String number2String = Integer.toString(number);
        binaryText.appendText(numberString + "/2= " + number2String + " Remainder "
        + remainderString + "\n");
        ToBinary(number / 2);      //Recurrsive call to method
    }
    return number;
}
} //End Class Sheppard_Week5
```

Comment: `binaryText` is declared as a local variable within the context of the `start` method, making it unavailable in any other parts of your app.  You should either make it an instance field of the class or pass it into the `ToBinary` method when the button is activated - but I can't see how the event handlers are setup, so that's just presumtions

Comment: In my whole code it is a global variable. I edited the code to relay that. Sorry!

Comment: So, how is `ToBinary` getting called?

Comment: I'd also beware, that calling `ToBinary` in the "main" thread could block it from updating the UI. You should have a look at [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) for more details

Comment: [Just my two cents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int))

Answer (score 0):

You simply never reach the call of the `ToBinary` method in `convertHandler.handle`:

```
if (enterText.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
    doA();
} 
else if (!enterText.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
    doB();
} else {
    doC();
}
```

can have exactly 3 outcomes:

1. An exception is thrown by `enterText.getText().trim().isEmpty()`, e.g. a `NullPointerException` and the code proceeds with the next surrounding `catch` block with an appropriate catch clause.
2. `enterText.getText().trim().isEmpty()` yields `true` and `doA()` is executed
3. `enterText.getText().trim().isEmpty()` yields `false` and `doB()` is executed

since your call to `toBinary` is in the `doC()` part, it's never executed. If you need to proceed if parsing succeeds you need to do this in the `try` block or exit the method in the `catch` block and put the logic from the last `else` right behind the last `catch`:

```
try {
    int enteredNumb = Integer.parseInt(enterText.getText());
    ToBinary(enteredNumb);
    Collections.reverse(remainderList);
    binaryText.appendText("-------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < remainderList.size(); i++){
        binaryText.setText(remainderList.get(i));
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle("Warning");
    alert.setHeaderText("Field is not an integer");
    alert.setContentText("The entered text is not an integer.\n"
            + "Please try again.");
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

or

```
int enteredNumb;
try {
    enteredNumb = Integer.parseInt(enterText.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle("Warning");
    alert.setHeaderText("Field is not an integer");
    alert.setContentText("The entered text is not an integer.\n"
            + "Please try again.");
    alert.showAndWait();
    return;
}

ToBinary(enteredNumb);
Collections.reverse(remainderList);
binaryText.appendText("-------------------------------\n");
for (int i = 0; i < remainderList.size(); i++){
    binaryText.setText(remainderList.get(i));
}
```

**Additional notes:**

- ```
  int remainder = number - 2 * (number / 2);
  ```

  there already is a way to do this in a single operation:

  ```
  int remainder = number % 2;
  ```

  In this case assuming non-negative `number` it can also be optimized using a binary operator which should be a bit faster than the remainder operator:

  ```
  int remainder = number & 1; // extract least significant bit
  ```
- I guess you're supposed to return something different from the `ToBinary` method. Otherwise you could easily use `void` as return type.
- If you want the remainders to be ordered from the most significant to the least significant bits, you need to do the recursive call before adding to the list. This way you don't need to reverse the list after the initial call to `toBinary`.
- You need to call `remainderList.clear()` unless you require the user to click the `clear` button between clicks on the `convert` button. Otherwise the list will still contain the last results.